# Parsec lookahead to handle ints

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm working on a Parsec parser to handle a somewhat complex data file format (and I have no control over this format).

I've made a lot of progress, but am currently stuck with the following.

I need to be able to parse a line somewhat like this:

```
4  0.123  1.452  0.667  *  3.460  149 - -
```

Semantically, the `4` is a nodeNum, the `Floats` and the `*` are negative log probabilities (so, `*` represents the negative log of probability zero). The `149` and the minus signs are really junk, which I can discard, but I need to at least make sure they don't break the parser.

Here's what I have so far:

This handles the "junk" I mentioned. It could probably be simpler, but it works by itself.

```
 emAnnotationSet = (,,) <$> p_int  <*>
                           (reqSpaces *> char '-') <*>
                           (reqSpaces *> char '-')
```

the `nodeNum` at the beginning of the line is handled by another parser that works and I need not get into.

The problem is in trying to pick out all the `p_logProb`s from the line, without consuming the digits at the beginning of the `emAnnotationSet`.

the parser for `p_logProb` looks like this:

```
p_logProb = liftA mkScore (lp <?> "logProb")
          where lp = try dub <|> string "*"
                dub = (++) <$> ((++) <$> many1 digit <*> string ".") <*> many1 digit
```

And finally, I try to separate the `logProb` entries from the trailing `emAnnotationSet` (which starts with an integer) as follows:

```
hmmMatchEmissions     = optSpaces *> (V.fromList <$> sepBy p_logProb reqSpaces) 
                      <* optSpaces <* emAnnotationSet <* eol 
                      <?> "matchEmissions"
```

So, `p_logProb` will only succeed on a float that begins with digits, includes a decimal point, and then has further digits (this restriction is respected by the file format).

I'd hoped that the `try` in the `p_logProb` definition would avoid consuming the leading digits if it didn't parse the decimal and the rest, but this doesn't seem to work; Parsec still complains that it sees an unexpected space after the digits of that integer in the `emAnnotationSet`:

```
Left "hmmNode" (line 1, column 196):
unexpected " "
expecting logProb
```

column 196 corresponds to the space after the integer preceding the minus signs, so it's clear to me that the problem is that the `p_logProb` parser is consuming the integer. How can I fix this so the `p_logProb` parser uses lookahead correctly, thus leaving that input for the `emAnnotationSet` parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integer which terminates the probabilities cannot be mistaken for a probability since it doesn't contain a decimal point.  The `lexeme` combinator converts a parser into one that skips trailing spaces.

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String
import Data.Char
import Control.Applicative ( (<$>), (<*>), (<$), (<*), (*>) )

fractional :: Fractional a => Parser a
fractional = try $ do
  n <- fromIntegral <$> decimal
  char '.'
  f <- foldr (\d f -> (f + fromIntegral (digitToInt d))/10.0) 0.0 <$> many1 digit  
  return $ n + f

decimal :: Parser Int
decimal = foldl (\n d -> 10 * n + digitToInt d) 0 <$> many1 digit

lexeme :: Parser a -> Parser a
lexeme p = p <* skipMany (char ' ')

data Row = Row Int [Maybe Double]
           deriving ( Show )

probability :: Fractional a => Parser (Maybe a)
probability = (Just <$> fractional) <|> (Nothing <$ char '*')

junk = lexeme decimal <* count 2 (lexeme $ char '-')

row :: Parser Row
row = Row <$> lexeme decimal <*> many1 (lexeme probability) <* junk

rows :: Parser [Row]
rows = spaces *> sepEndBy row (lexeme newline) <* eof
```

**Usage:**

```
*Main> parseTest rows "4 0.123 1.234 2.345 149 - -\n5 0.123 * 2.345 149 - -" 
[Row 4 [Just 0.123,Just 1.234,Just 2.345],Row 5 [Just 0.123,Nothing,Just 2.345]]
```

Comment: I think I can get this to what I need. Those asterisks should not become Nothing actually; they and the doubles actually become instances of Score, but I've got constructors for those so it should be a trivial change. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure of your problem. However, to parse the line given based on your description, it would be much easier to use existing lexers define in `Text.Parsec.Token1`, and join them together.

The below code parses the line into a Line data type, you can process it further from there if necessary. Instead of attempting to filter out the `-` and integers before parsing, it uses a `parseEntry` parser that returns a `Just Double` if it is a Float value, `Just 0` for `*`, and `Nothing` for integers and dashes. This is then very simply filtered using `catMaybes`.

Here is the code:

```
module Test where
import Text.Parsec
import qualified Text.Parsec.Token as P
import Text.Parsec.Language (haskellDef)
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Data.Maybe (catMaybes)
lexer = P.makeTokenParser haskellDef

parseFloat = P.float lexer
parseInteger = P.natural lexer 

whiteSpace = P.whiteSpace lexer

parseEntry = try (Just <$> parseFloat)
             <|> try (const (Just 0) <$> (char '*' >> whiteSpace))
             <|> try (const Nothing <$> (char '-' >> whiteSpace))
             <|> (const Nothing <$> parseInteger)


data Line = Line {
      lineNodeNum :: Integer
    , negativeLogProbabilities :: [Double]
    } deriving (Show)

parseLine = do
  nodeNum <- parseInteger
  whiteSpace
  probabilities <- catMaybes <$> many1 parseEntry
  return $ Line { lineNodeNum = nodeNum, negativeLogProbabilities = probabilities }
```

Example usage:

```
*Test> parseTest parseLine "4  0.123  1.452  0.667  *  3.460  149 - -"
Line {lineNodeNum = 4, negativeLogProbabilities = [0.123,1.452,0.667,0.0,3.46]}
```

The only issue that may (or may not) be a problem is it will parse `*-` as two different tokens, rather than fail at parsing. Eg

```
*Test> parseTest parseLine "4  0.123  1.452  0.667  *  3.460  149 - -*"
Line {lineNodeNum = 4, negativeLogProbabilities = [0.123,1.452,0.667,0.0,3.46,0.0]}
```

Note the extra `0.0` at the end of the log probabilities.

Comment: hmm... the problem is, '*' should not be parsed as 0.0; it's the _negative log_ of 0, so it's really infinity (treated as `negLogZero`). And, stripping an extraneous `0.0` off the end of the list seems really unfortunate... I'm also leery of using the existing lexers, because the floats in this file format are not actually arbitrary floats (for example, they cannot be negative, and e-notation is not allowed).

Comment: really, I need to parse a bunch of tokens that are either '*' or floats using, decimal notation, followed by a single integer (and then two minus signs). That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: ahh, I misunderstood your point about the extra 0.0. No, I'm not worried about `-*` showing up. I am still worried about using the lexer. I don't want to allow arbitrary ints in the list of allowed doubles and `*`s. To clarify, the int and minus signs are always at the end of the line, immediately preceding the `eol`.